# Use of Date Strings in Datawindow Filters

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

In a number of datawindows in my application, users have access to a free-form text box where they can enter any filter string they like.  Frequently, they will successfully use a search term like:
    `date(last_updated_date) = 2010-10-22`

I'm trying to update some documentation and have been asked to address this syntax in particular.  So my question is this: how does PowerBuilder know that "2010-10-22" is a date and what are the rules for including date literals like this one without specific conversion? Is it based upon the fact that the left-hand value is clearly a date datatype or is it based upon the particular date format used in "2010-10-22" or both?  Just to be clear: this syntax woks properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely the format for literal dates (without quotes), and there is no need to compare with the left side of the comparison to handle it as a date.

In the "Standard dataypes" section, the documentation states for the type "Date":

> The date, including the full year (1000 to 3000), the number of the
>   month (01 to 12), and the day (01 to 31).  Using literals   To assign
>   a literal value, separate the year, month, and day with hyphens. For
>   example:
>
> 2001-12-25  // December 25, 2001
>
> 2003-02-06  // February 6, 2003

Answer (score 0):

All what Seki said about the literals it’s true. If you want/have to use strings however, the format „yyyy-mm-dd” is the one that will always work when comparing with/assigning to a date type variable. It’s considered the standard for date format.

If a different string format is used as a date, for example „25-12-2012”, PB uses Windows regional settings to convert it. If conversion fails you’ll get 1900-01-01.

You can also check PB help „Date PowerScript function/Convert a string to a date”.